# why is prev the return variable solution?

Tags: python, function, class, while-loop, linked-list

so i found this code solution for leetcode #206 (reverse linked list) and i kept wondering why variable prev is the solution?

the code is:

```
class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
        # setting pointers
        prev, curr = None, head

        while curr is not None:
            nxt = curr.next
            curr.next = prev
            prev = curr
            curr = nxt
        return prev
```

lets set a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] linked list
at the end of the iterations prev points to the last node (5). then why returning prev is the solution if prev is just a node and not the entire linked list.

Comment: You are given the `head` of a linked-list. When it is reversed the new head becomes the original last node and so the solution returns that as the head of the new linked-list. You could use that head to go through the whole list. The leetcode solutions include a video of the solution code in Python processing the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in a linked list, each node *is a list in and of itself*. An empty list is denoted by the `None` value, and any non-None value is considered the first element of the list. But more importantly, that head node will have a link to the next value, and so on recursively, so you have all the information you need to iterate over the entire list.

You can also think of the link as a subslice: `head.next` is roughly equivalent to `list[1:]`, i.e., a slice starting at the second element. And `head.next.next` would be `list[2:]`. So just `head` would be `list[0:]`, i.e., the entire list.